# What is the meaning of a statement regarding the result of interview?

Tags: job, faculty-application, interview

I did an interview for a faculty position around 1 and half month ago. I recently sent a follow up email regarding the status of my application, and the chair of faculty replied that my application is with the dean. What is the meaning of `with dean`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Faculty hiring after campus interview](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166210/faculty-hiring-after-campus-interview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most useful information you can draw from this e-mail is that the fate of your application is not decided yet. You need to be a bit more patient.

Another bit of information is that the chair of faculty sometimes has poor communication, since they make statements that are a little confusing for a person that doesn't have knowledge of their internal processes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point is that I have been offered other positions and I still waiting for a clear reply from this one.

Comment: @user40491 I think that there's an existing question about that situation on this website (no time to search currently)

Comment: While this answer is correct, I would take the statement as positive, rather than negative. It is unlikely to have been sent to the dean, IMO, unless it was sent with a positive recommendation. Maybe not glowing (impossible to judge that), but positive. A negative opinion would be more likely to be handled by the department, perhaps with a recommendation to the dean that "we keep looking".

Comment: @user40491 does the chair know that you have other offers? It’s really important that you tell them, including any decision deadlines that you have for accepting the other offers.

Comment: @DanRomik Today I sent an email explaining that I have another offer and waiting for his reply